# Get metric depth map from Kinect 2

Tags: kinect, ros, point-cloud-library

I have installed libfreenect2 and iai_kinect2 for working on PCL and ROS on my Kinect. I have been working on how to get depth map data from Kinect 2. I have been able to see and check for `rostopic list` but I am not able to understand how to get depth data in metres rather than integers.

When running `rostopic list`, I get the following topics: 
[rostopic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOiF0.png)

When running `rosnode list`, I get the following output:
[rosnode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bknHn.png)

Which of those topics will give me the depth map information from the kinect (kinect v2)? I have echoed all the topics (using `rostopic echo <topic name>`) and all the topics publish values in [0, 255] range. I am not able to understand how do I get depth map, which (ideally) should be in floating point and not in discrete 0-255 range?

Also, what are those additional rosnodes, with points_xyzrgb_ appended to their name and how do I make use of them? Do I have to write some additional program to somehow extract depth map --- if so, how?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not make screenshots of terminal outputs but rather copy the text and add it directly in the question.

Comment: Regarding your question: What is the type of the message? It is probably pointcloud2, which, as far as I remember, internally always stores the values byte-wise in one big array, independent of their type. You have to convert it to the correct PCL pointcloud type in your code to access it.

Comment: I changed to title of your question to what, I think, reflects the actual question better. Feel free to change it again if you don't agree.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the depth map, you have to subscribe to the topic: `/kinect2/sd/image_depth`, than you can use the image in the way you want.

I don't know if you need depth image for your application, but the topics `/kinect2/sd/points` and `/kinect2/hd/points` gives you a message of type `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2`. You can use methods from PCL to convert the message to a PCL pointcloud (`pcl::fromROSMsg`) and then back to a ROS message (`pcl::toROSMsg`). You have to include `pcl_conversions`

Comment: ok i am pure beginner ,by including you mean i have to include pcl_conversions package from github and then make  with my package again and use methods to convert right?

Comment: you should already have pcl_conversions...add it in the project in your CMakeLists.txt inside find_package like in this snippet: 
`find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  roslib
  std_msgs
  pcl_conversions
)`

Then you have to add build and run dependencies in your package.xml
  `<build_depend>pcl_ros</build_depend>
  <run_depend>pcl_conversions</run_depend>`

Finally, in your code:
`#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>`

Comment: can we use pcl_ros package pointcloud_to_pcd as kinectv2 provide message of type sensor_msgs/PointCloud2?